# Error when creating list of time series linear models with a loop

Tags: r, for-loop, forecast

I have the following data set (code requires the `forecast` package for the `tslm` call.

```
x <- rnorm(11, mean = 534, sd = 79)
y <- rnorm(9, mean = 800, sd = 56)
p <- list(x, y) 
tsl <- list(); ts_trend <- list()


for(i in seq_along(p)) {

    tsl[[i]] <- ts(p[[i]], start = c(2018, 1), frequency = 52)
}

    for(i in seq_along(tsl)) {

ts_trend[[i]] <- tslm(tsl[[i]] ~ trend)

}
```

When I run it, I get the error

```
Error in tsl[[i]] : subscript out of bounds
```

The subscript, to my knowledge, is clearly not out of bounds.  I use the same reference in the prior loop, with no error.

I have no idea how to fix this.  What am I missing?

Comment: You have two `for` loops.  i think the nested is not needed. `for(i in seq_along(tsl)) ts_trend[[i]] <- tslm(tsl[[i]] ~ trend)`

Comment: You can actually combine both for one `for` loop. What is *trend*?

Comment: sorry @akrun that was a typo error which I've fixed.  @Parfait trend is an argument only for the `tslm` call.  You can call `trend` and the coef will be the linear trend for the time series object.  You can also construct the call `tslm(x ~ trend + season)` and season will product seasonality coefficients as well as trend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `lapply` and it would work

```
ts_trendN <- lapply(tsl, function(x) tslm(x ~ trend))
```

---

The reason why `for` loop is not working is based on the environment on which `trend` is calculated.  We can create a new environment and it would work fine

```
for(i in seq_along(tsl)) {
   ev1 <- new.env()
   ev1$tsl1 <- tsl[[i]]

    ts_trend[[i]] <- tslm(ev1$tsl1 ~ trend)


   }
```

There may be some difference in attributes.  The model output is the same

```
library(broom)
identical(tidy(ts_trendN[[1]]), tidy(ts_trend[[1]]))
#[1] TRUE
```

Comment: Aaaaahhhh...I must have run the debugger 10 times and I found out where the error occurred but I didn't understand the nature of the call.  This is brilliant...thank you! 
    eval(mf, parent.frame())
The `parent.frame()` call references the global environment, but I really don't know this affects the call I was making directly.  Any advice on how to learn more about environmental issues and and function calls?